# 'function "jsonify" not defined' error while trying to deploy in hugo

Tags: hugo

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed Hugo using :

`sudo apt-get install hugo`

My hugo version :

`Hugo Static Site Generator v0.16-DEV BuildDate: 2016-02-06T12:14:17-05:00`

I was trying to deploy hugo-theme-bleak as per the [Quick start tutorial](https://gohugo.io/overview/quickstart/) in Hugo website.

After cloning the theme using

`git clone https://github.com/Zenithar/hugo-theme-bleak.git`

I tried running hugo server using following command :

`hugo server --theme=hugo-theme-bleak --buildDrafts`

But I'm getting the following error , and the page is not generated properly.

```
ERROR: 2017/07/15 12:40:28 server.go:121: port 1313 already in use, 
attempting to use an available port

ERROR: 2017/07/15 12:40:28 template.go:350: template: theme/partials
/header.html:112: function "jsonify" not defined

ERROR: 2017/07/15 12:40:28 template.go:350: template: theme/partials
/pagination.html:4: function "slice" not defined

ERROR: 2017/07/15 12:40:28 template.go:119: html/template: 
"theme/partials/header.html" is an incomplete template in theme/partials
/header.html

ERROR: 2017/07/15 12:40:28 template.go:119: html/template: 
"theme/partials/pagination.html" is an incomplete template in 
theme/partials/pagination.html

ERROR: 2017/07/15 12:40:28 template.go:119: html/template: 
"theme/partials/header.html" is an incomplete template in theme/partials
/header.html

ERROR: 2017/07/15 12:40:28 template.go:119: html/template: 
"theme/partials/header.html" is an incomplete template in theme/partials
/header.html

ERROR: 2017/07/15 12:40:28 template.go:119: html/template: 
"theme/partials/pagination.html" is an incomplete template in 
theme/partials/pagination.html

1 of 1 draft rendered
0 future content
1 pages created
0 non-page files copied
2 paginator pages created
0 categories created
0 tags created
in 15 ms
```

The same sort of 'function not defined' error popping up with several other themes also, which I tried.

Any ideas on how to fix ?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.! 
The error is because the installed version of Hugo is too old. 
apt repositories have very old version of hugo in it. 
It is advised to download '.deb' packages for ubuntu systems from the git releases page of hugo directly.